# Can IntegrityLevel of a process be changed after the process was started?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm referring to the `Integrity Level` that can be retrieved via [GetTokenInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`(TokenIntegrityLevel)` API call.

Comment: I don't believe so.  But it might be possible to effectively change the integrity level of a thread via impersonation.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: "Integrity level of a thread", I thought the integrity level applies on a process scope. Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: [What is the Windows Integrity Mechanism?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625957.aspx) "Integrity levels must be assigned automatically to every security access token during access token creation, so that every process *and thread* has an effective integrity level for access control." (emphasis mine)

Comment: ... but I'm not sure what that means in practical terms.  Some UIPI restrictions naturally apply to threads, e.g., posting windows messages.  However the [documentation for PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says "The thread of a process can post messages only to message queues of threads in processes of lesser or equal integrity level" which implies that it is the integrity level of the process, rather than that of the thread, that counts.

Comment: However I would *guess* that the UIPI restrictions on accessing files (and other securable objects) *are* affected by impersonation.  So a thread in a high integrity process that is impersonating a medium integrity token probably can't write to a high integrity file.  (It probably works the other way around, too, except that IIRC under normal circumstances a thread in a medium integrity process won't have impersonation privilege.)